# Customizing Longclaw ProductIndex page

Tags: django, wagtail

Longclaw/Wagtail newbie here. Wagtail CMS provides an overridable get_context method that makes it possible to pass dictionary values into the template. From the [documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context):

```
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    ...

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(BlogIndexPage, self).get_context(request)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        context['blog_entries'] = BlogPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
        return context
```

Longclaw is an eCommerce project built on top of Wagtail. Longclaw has an inbuilt Page model called ProductIndex. Is there any way to pass variables into the ProductIndex template, like I can with get_context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. It does not currently support this, but it would be great if it could. I recommend raising an issue on GitHub so we can't get this into development (https://github.com/JamesRamm/longclaw)

It may be possible to dynamically add the function;

```
def get_context(...):
    ....

ProductIndex.get_context = get_context
```

Ive not tried it so can't say for certain that it will work!